# How to partially update a realm object

Tags: java, android, realm

How do I update a realm object partially?

Imagine I have a model like this:

```
class Person {
    @PrimaryKey long id;
    String name;
    Address address;
}
```

Let's assume I sync my local realm database with a backend and the backend gives me only a `Person` with `id` and `name` where the name has changed (no address).

How do I update only the `Person.name` ? Furthermore, I want `Person.address` stay as it is in the local database.

Comment: you have to do it manually. Query the `id` on the Realm, update start transaction update the value you got from the server and commit

Comment: Is there really no other way? Sounds painful ...

Comment: I've seent this question before and one guy from the Realm team answered here that. I can't find the link now but u can search back on it. Yep, it's painful. It would be great if there was an `update` method with null check.

Comment: @Budius technically you should start the transaction, query the `id` on the Realm. update the value you got and then commit. (or cancel in case of failure)

Comment: If you are using `Realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson()` (and other JSON related API), it will ignore the field doesn't exist in the JSON object. That means the field will be set to the default value if the object doesn't exist, or keep the original value if the object with same primary key exist.

Answer (score 9):

You can only insert/copy/update entire objects, you can't specify "what fields you don't want to save". So you should query your object and set its stuff and then save it back.

```
final Address address = getAddress();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Person person = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo(PersonFields.ID, id).findFirst();
        if(person == null) {
            person = new Person();  // or realm.createObject(Person.class, id);
            person.id = id; 
        }
        person.address = address;
        realm.insertOrUpdate(person);
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't we do `if(!person.isManaged()) realm.insertOrUpdate(person);` in last line? Because if it is managed, address will already be changed directly in `person.address = address`.

Answer (score 4):

To update the `Person.name` you need to first query the `Person` object and then update its `name`. All other fields will remain unchanged:

```
long id = ... // from backend
String newName = ... // from backend
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
Person person = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
person.setName(newName);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```